# How to call a function in a local function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, amazon-s3

The following Code returns that setState is not a function, but only when its called inside a local function like the function in s3.getObject etc.

```
s3.getObject({
      Bucket: bucket, 
      Key: key
    }, function (error, data) {
      if (error != null) {
        console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
      } else {
        this.setState({data: data});
    })
```

Comment: Because `this` here doesn't point to the class component, but to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Function scope

If you use the `function` keyword to make a function it will create a new scope. To access the current scope we use the `this` keyword. Since `setState` is in the scope of the parent and not in the current function scope you will not be able to access it.

You can use `bind` as suggested by EvanMorrison, or you could use the fat arrow function to pass scope through.
The advantage to passing scope is that you do not have to "mess" around with the `bind` function that can be confusing to some developers.

```
s3.getObject({
  Bucket: bucket, 
  Key: key  
}, (error, data) => {
  if (error != null) {
    console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
  } else {
    this.setState({data: data});
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

"this" is no longer pointing to your react component when it's inside the local function. Try `this.setState({data: data}).bind(this)`.